# ec2 run-instances user-data script - changing user from root to ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am using aws cli to launch ec2 instances. I am using the user-data parameter to run a custom script when they are launched:

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
......
    --user-data file://~/Desktop/script.sh
```

In script.sh i can see that it is running it user root user
for example when i run

```
whoami > testwhoami.txt
```

i can see root in the text file

I need to switch the user to **ubntu** and it doesn't seem to work.
I have tried many things in this script:

```
sudo su -l ubuntu
su -l ubuntu &> output.txt
```

but after all these whoami keeps showing that **root** is the user and output.txt is empty as well

What might cause this? How can i debug it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your command `su -l ubuntu` returns an interactive shell, which is useless when you're running a script (EC2 user-data).

You need to submit your command using `su` `-c` option like this:

`su ubuntu -c 'whoami' > output.txt`

Comment: I see that you put the whoami command inline. How can i make it work on a different line? (How can i change the user so that all the next commands in the file will be done using that user?)